# Find and Replace to track URLs in Notepad++

Tags: javascript, notepad++

I have a file that contains around thousands of lines. Format of every line is as below:

```
02:17:15.204    1.217   890 322 GET 200 text/html   http://stage.youbeauty.com/body-fitness/galleries/gluten-free-bodycare
02:17:16.530    0.304   313 (7592)  GET (Cache) text/javascript http://use.typekit.com/lqi6pyj.js
02:17:16.534    0.769   463 (8631)  GET 304 text/css    http://stage.assets0.youbeauty.com/rel-20120404171521/assets/vendor.css
02:17:16.537    1.514   419 32963   GET 200 text/css    http://stage.assets0.youbeauty.com/rel-20120404171521/assets/application1.css
```

I want to get only the URLs with the help of "Find and Replace" functionality in NOtepad++.

(It is also fine if we use any script like java script )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Regular Expression option, and this search term:

```
http.*
```

This will select everything from the `http` to the end of the line.

If you want to remove everything but the URL on each line, use this:

```
Find what: .*(http.*)
Replace with: \1
```

Comment: +1. cool..! You are Master in Notepad++. You should be part of npp development.

Comment: I'm good at using NP++, that doesn't mean I could develop it. Just like many people who use Photoshop would be completely lost trying to make it.

Answer (score 2):

I have written a python script. Here it is http://ideone.com/TkK5e. Hope it helps.